# Ansible in multi environments

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I was wondering if anyone could advise on how I can manage multi environment variables using ansible. Imagine i have development and staging. I have the following structure:

```
.
├── inventories
│   ├── development
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   └── all.yml
│   │   └── hosts
│   └── staging
│       ├─── group_vars
│       │   └── all.yml
│   │   └── hosts
├── roles
└── test.yml
```

In each all.yml file, i have one variable like this:

vars:
name:"development"

I was wondering how is the best approach to load the values depending on a parameter to set for example on command line (-i env=development).

In test.yml, I have this:

```
- name: test playbook
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
 
  tasks:
    - name: 
      debug: 
        var: name
```

When I execute, I get this:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/development/ test.yml  -vvv
....
ok: [localhost] => {
    "name": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'name' is undefined"
}
```

I'm kind of new to ansible and I've found thousands of different ways and I was wondering what is the best approach? Because I'm kind of lost :( :(

Regards,

Comment: The best approach is usually to manage that in your inventory(ies). But I'm not sure we are talking about the same "environment". It is usually something like development, testing, production.... you seem to talk about the kind of individuals that will be using the playbook. Is your playbook supposed to deploy on the same set of targets and get a different result depending on whom is running it ? (I would actually find this kind of weird). Anyway, I think your question is a bit broad and lacking details to be answered easily.

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator; you're right. I meant staging, production and development. Do you have any good documentation explainin gthis with a sample directory? and how to configure this?

Comment: Then you can edit your question to make this more clear to everyone. Best place to start IMO: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_best_practices.html, more specifically the paragraphs on directory layout and alternative directory layout.

Comment: I have added more details :)
Thank you

Comment: I guess this is not the right way to proceed... I've been getting crazy because of this :(

Answer (score 1):

We have something similar to your needs on our project, I guess.
Organized in below maner:

```
.
group_vars folder
├── all.yml # variables common for all envs (creds for example)
├── development.yml # variables for development env
└── staging.yml # variables for staging env
|
invenory_file.yml # file which stoers your managed hosts list devided by groups
├── [development]
│   ├── dev.host1.name # development host#1 with vars applied from development.yml
│   ├── dev.host2.name # development host#2 with vars applied from development.yml
│   └── dev.host3.name # development host#3 with vars applied from development.yml
├── [staging]
│   ├── staging.host1.name # staging host#1 with vars applied from staging.yml
│   ├── staging.host2.name # staging host#2 with vars applied from staging.yml
│   └── staging.host3.name # staging host#3 with vars applied from staging.yml
|
roles
```

Main idea that you have separate files with vars for different envs, and you have your hosts organized in environments groups in inventory file. So variables from files in group_vars will applied to correct hosts grouped in Inventory.

Here is usuful link to check on how Ansible groups are organized:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html